# concatenate nested enum string in swift

Tags: swift, enums

I want to declare an enum type (say, ParentEnum) which will be used as an argument of a function, it contains a number of "child" enums and each case of the child enum uses the name of the child enum as a prefix, here's an example:

```
enum ParentEnum: String {
    enum ChildEnum1: String {
        case c1 = "/ChildEnum1/c1"
        case c2 = "/ChildEnum1/c2"
    }
    enum ChildEnum2: String {
        case c1 = "/ChildEnum2/c1"
        case c2 = "/ChildEnum2/c2"
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to generalize the "/ChildEnumX" part so I only need to define "/cX" as its rawValue, and when I call `ParentEnum.ChildEnumX.c1`, it will give me "/ChildEnumX/c1" like the example above.

I hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.

Comment: Implement [`CustomStringConvertible.description`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible). That gives you a single central place to prepend whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remembered to update this post in case someone else has the same problem, this is what I came up with:

```
enum ParentEnum {
    case Child1(ChildEnum1)
    case Child2(ChildEnum2)

    enum ChildEnum1: String {
        case c1 = "/c1"
        case c2 = "/..."
    }
    enum ChildEnum2: String {
        case c1 = "/..."
        case c2 = "/..."
    }
    ...
    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .Child1(let child):
            return "ChildEnum1/\(child.rawValue)"
        case .Child2(let child):
            return "ChildEnum2/\(child.rawValue)"
        }
    }
}
```

if you were using ParentEnum as an argument of a function, `.Child1(.c1).rawValue` would yield `"ChildEnum1/c1"`. You could also override the `rawValue` of the Child enums to further extend the nesting levels. Hope this helps.