# Print all cases in nested enums - Swift

Tags: swift, enums, case, iterable

[Printing all cases in an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56858018/1389515) is super simple!

Now I need to print all cases in the nested enum. My enum is like:

```
enum OuterEnum: String, CaseIterable {
        
        case a = "A"
        case b = "B"
        
        enum InnerEnum: String, CaseIterable {
            case c = "C"
        }
}
```

If I try to print all elements by `allCases` property, only **a** & **b** are getting printed. But, my expectation is,

`printEnumCases(OuterEnum.self)` should print all the cases like

```
A
B
C
```

Can someone help in this?

**Additional question:** Also, I want to know about the difference between `allCases` & `AllCases` properties of an enum.

Thanks!!

Comment: `allCases` is the instance value `AllCases` represent its type

Comment: this sould be fix your problem. [concatenate nested enum string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991478/concatenate-nested-enum-string-in-swift)

Comment: I don't want to include initialisers/variables in each enum. I just want to pass the entire enum to a function to print its whole elements.